# Unable to "cd" into an external drive

Tags: 11.04, command-line, filesystem

I am new to Linux. So please excuse me if my question is amateur.

I have two partitions: "Windows and Linux OS" 
Both are listed as Storage-Files, called under the name of "New Volume"

The external drive is mounted under `/media/New Volume/..` but I am unable to "cd" into the drives' file system. I can get into the drives' files ystem with gnome, but i am unable to get in via terminal. Is this related to the Volumes name?

(New Volume) the space between "New" and "Volume"

Please help..

Comment: It's just `/media/New Volume`, no `..`.  The `..` means the parent directory, which would put you back in `/media`.

Answer (score 5):

it's likely the space in the name.

from the command line you should use:
`cd /media/New\ Volume`
or
`cd "/media/New Volume"`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
cd /media/New\ Volume
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply drag & drop your `New Volume` into Terminal and you'll see, that both previous comments are the solution to your question. Drag and drop works also with any kind of file and folder.

You can also enclose the argument with single quotes `'New Volume'` or double quotes `"New Volume"`

---

Also [nautilus-terminal](http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/) might be of interest, since it migrates to your file browser window(s) and enables you to see the `cd` (change directory) path, which is automatically executed when you move to another folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If a folder or file name contains whitespaces you can do three things in terminal:

- Use the Tab key to auto complete the name
- Write the name in quotes `cd /media/"New Volume"/`
- Escape the whitespace with an `\` character `cd /media/New\ Volume/`